# Objective-C class not recognized

Tags: objective-c, ios, class

I'm new to Objective-C and I'm trying to use the [UIImage+Resize class](https://github.com/mbcharbonneau/UIImage-Categories) to resize a picture in iOS. See `UIIimage+Resize.m` code.

The resizeImage class is not recognized by XCode in the following code.

> Error message: "Class method resizedImage:interpolationQuality not
>   found..."

```
#import "UIImage+Resize.h"

- (void)useImage:(UIImage*)theImage { 

 ...
 ...
 ...

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake (newWidth, newHeight);
    CGInterpolationQuality InterpQual = kCGInterpolationHigh;

    UIImage* newImg = [UIImage resizedImage:newSize interpolationQuality:InterpQual];


 ...
 ...
 ...
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling that method as if it was a class method (`[UIImage ...]`) however it's an instance method (note the leading `-`).  So you need an instance of `UIImage` to call it on instead.

Comment: Correct answer, the instance he meant to use is probably theImage. So it should be `[theImage resizedImage:newSize interpolationQuality:InterpQual]`

Comment: @user506706 You shouldn't correct the question. The problem should remain in the question so that future viewers will see what was wrong. The post in it's current form will make it look like that code gives the class method not found error, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

create an instance of UIImage before calling resize methode